# Convert a date saved in @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS" format to @"dd MM" for display convenience

Tags: iphone, date, sqlite, date-format

I have saved a date in @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS" format,Now in database it gets displayed in what ever format specified! But I have a requirement of displaying date in view reminder page.Hence I would like to display date in such a way that the visibility of date is simple in appearance.

Hence I would like to have the date with say the format:January 23 or August 19 etc...

I have tried the below code but its not displaying any date:

```
remin.Date = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statament, 3)]autorelease];

                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd"];
                NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remin.Date];
                NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
                remin.Date = dateVal;
```

Please provide a solution through your valuable suggestions

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: convert NSString to NSDate and then again NSDate to NSString back

Comment: ok you have done in incorrect way let me write code for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code

```
remin.Date = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statament, 3)]autorelease];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remin.Date];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
remin.Date = dateVal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as,

```
remin.Date = [[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statament, 3)]autorelease];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remin.Date];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM"];
NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
remin.Date = dateVal;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the `NSDateFormatter` the date format of the string, before you parse it.

```
NSString *orginaleDate = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statament, 3)];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

// Set the date format as stored in the date base
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:remin.Date];

// set the date format for the representation 
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM-dd"];
NSString *dateVal = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
remin.Date = dateVal;

[orginaleDate release], orginaleDate =nil;
```

You might want to also store the time zone in the datebase, but this depends on the apps requirements. To add the time use this format `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS z`

Comment: Thank you very much it worked,I have exhibited my regards in the form of upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code:-

```
NSString *dateString = @"15-08-2011 05:12:36";
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS"];
NSDate *currentDate = [format dateFromString:dateString];

[format setDateFormat:@"dd MM"];
NSString *newDateString = [format stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked,I have exhibited my regards in the form of upvote :)